# Unable to avoid the page breaking of a list in visualforce PDF

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, table

I have to do a visualforce that render a list of list of quotelineitem, that can be spited on more page cause the visualforce is seted to renderAs="pdf".
To reach my goal i decide to use an apex repeat nested in another apex repeat.
Each list represents a group of qli , my goal is to impose at the iteration to pagebreak only entire grop.

my code actualy is like this example :

```
<table>
<apex:repeat value="{!QLIG}" var="group" >
  <apex:variable var="num" value="{!0}" />
  <tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;" >
     <apex:repeat value="{!group}" var="item" >
          <tr style="height:35px;page-break-inside:avoid;">
          <td  class="data_table_s">{!item.pn__c}</td>
          <td  class="data_table_m">{!item.cc__c}</td>
          <td  class="data_table_s">{!item.pr__c}</td>
          <td class="data_table_m">{!item.dp__c}</td>
          <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!num==0}">
          <td class="data_table_s" rowspan="{!group.size}" style="page-break-inside:avoid;">{!ROUND(item.qt__c, 2) }</td> 
          </apex:outputPanel>
          <td class="data_table_m">{!item.ic__c}</td>
          <td  class="data_table_s">{!item.up__c}</td>
          <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!item.vc__c>=0}">
          <td   style="color:green;" class="data_table_m">{!item.vc__c}</td>
          </apex:outputPanel>
          <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!item.vc__c<0}">
          <td  style="color:red;" class="data_table_m">{!item.vc__c}</td>
          </apex:outputPanel>
          </tr>
          <apex:variable var="num" value="{!num + 1}"/>
      </apex:repeat> 
  </tr> 
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

So the first apex repeat iterate over the list of group of qli and the inner apex repeat iterate over each qli of the group .
I try to wrap the whole group in tr where i specified in ccs to "page-break-inside:avoid" because if a entire group can stay on the same page remains there, otherwise the whole group goes to the next page.
This solution unfortunately doesn't work .
How can i reach the Goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often assumed that the Visualforce PDF generation is done using [Flying Saucer](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html) and that documentation says:

> Flying Saucer supports all of the CSS page-break properties.
>
> The only limitation is that `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`
>   with value avoid only considers siblings vs. all margins which meet at
>   that location (as the spec dictates).
>
> If a rule cannot be satisfied (e.g. a `<div style="page-break-inside:
>   avoid;">` spans three pages), the rule is simply dropped as if it never
>   existed.

No mention of tables in that but elsewhere:

> -fs-table-paginate
> when used with the value paginate, modifies the table layout algorithm to repeat table headers and footers on
>   subsequent pages and improve the appearance of cells that break across
>   pages (for example by closing and reopening borders), but that's all
>   it does. If a table's minimum width is wider than the page, it will be
>   chopped off.

I suggest you read that documentation further to see if there are other options/limitations documented and also review these https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems to me that what you described to me is not an integrated solution to salesforce but something external, do you confirm?

Comment: @riccardo_castellano Salesforce incorporates other software into their platform, and for this job of PDF generation they have incorporated Flying Saucer.

Comment: Ok, many thanks , now i understand

Comment: i go to this url https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_5  that seams to be a guide to flying saucer . i try  to use -fs-keep-with-inline:keep in  front of page-break-inside:avoid; but the the result is that the table break the column size

Comment: @riccardo_castellano Sorry to hear that. Suggest you keep looking around for ideas e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf.